# Test coverage observable

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, rxjs, jasmine

Im having a hard time to cover this map statements on my unit tests:
[test coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8AMq.png)

I think I should subscribe to the observables segmentedLandingPages$ and globalLandingPages$ to cover the maps, but I can't figure it out how.

This is the test file:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { LandingPageModel } from './../../model/landing-page.model';
import { LandingPageService } from './../../services/landing-page.service';
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, async, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { OverviewComponent } from './overview.component';

describe('OverviewComponent', () => {
  let component: OverviewComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<OverviewComponent>;
  let mockRouter = {
    navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')
  };
  let mockFormGroup: FormGroup = { reset() { } } as FormGroup;
  let mockFormBuilder = {
    group() { return mockFormGroup }
  }
  let mockLandingPageService = {
    getSegmentedLandingPages: () => of([{} as LandingPageModel, {} as LandingPageModel]),
    getGlobalLandingPages: () => of([{} as LandingPageModel, {} as LandingPageModel]),
    landingPageToEdit: jasmine.createSpy('landingPageToEdit')
  }

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        OverviewComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter },
        { provide: FormBuilder, useValue: mockFormBuilder },
        { provide: LandingPageService, useValue: mockLandingPageService }
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OverviewComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should test ngOnInit setTimeout', fakeAsync(() => {
    expect(() => component.ngOnInit()).not.toThrow();
    tick(2000);
  }));
```

Comment: The problem is that those lines are never excuted at all, there is no subscription or assignment.

Comment: Hello Moxxi, 
Yeah i thought so, but I can't figure it out how to subscribe during the test because the observables are assigned to those variables segmentedLandingPages$ and globalLandingPages$
I tried to subscribe to those variables on beforeEach and afterEach but had no success